# 'Qt +=charts' has been removed in Qt 6.0. How can I draw a line chart now?

Tags: c++, qt

I need to draw a line chart in a project of Qt 6.0.3.
But the module 'charts' in Qt 5.0 has been removed.
Is there any new module to draw a line chart?

Comment: If you can wait a bit, Qt 6.1 will have charts support: https://www.qt.io/blog/add-on-support-in-qt-6.0-and-beyond

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not. As mentioned by @IHerdULiekLambdas [it is on the roadmap for 6.1](https://www.qt.io/blog/add-on-support-in-qt-6.0-and-beyond).

You might look into alternative plotting library or stay with Qt 5.x for the time being. In general Qt 6.0 is not deemed production-ready.

In general, a good alternative might be [KQuickCharts](https://api.kde.org/frameworks/kquickcharts/html/index.html), using QtQuick, however I don't know if it already works with Qt 6. Note that QtCharts is GPL-licensed or commercial license. KQuickCharts is LGPL-licensed.